# AWS Elastic Beanstalk, converting default environment to https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have made an elastic beanstalk environment, which is running on http. Environment is made for java application, and i am directly running the jar snapshot in environment. Now i want the elastic beanstalk to run in https, currently the default url is in http. So please help me out how can i make the urls in https, i am using default url given by elastic beanstalk itself.

Comment: Installing a valid SSL cert for your custom domain on your ELB is the easiest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you would want to do this through AWS Elastic Beanstalk Console.

You should first select the 'Capacity' option and select 'Load Balanced' from the 'Auto Scaling Group' Drop Down and select other options as required (you can keep max instances to 1, if you need only 1 instance running).

This enables the load balancer options in the main configurations screen, where you can add an additional listener for port 443 and generate and include an amazon issued certificate. The Load Balancer will then transfer the requests to port 443 (https).

Also take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html